# How to login as different user inside shell script and execute a set of commands?

Tags: bash, shell-script

My requirement is to login as a different user which requires password authentication and execute some commands as that user inside a shell script which I run from my user account.

example: user1 is executing the script. Requirement is to login as user2 using password and execute set of commands using a single shell script.

Comment: Is password authentication required? Solutions I can think of would require the password to be stored more or less unencrypted in the script, which should not be done. If possible, I would prefer to use `ssh otheruser@localhost` with keypair for authentication.

Answer (score 8):

You can use several ways:

1. Using `su`. Via su you can exec the command on this way:

`su user -c "command"`

or

```
su - user -c "command"
```

the difference is when you have dash you will get the environment of target user. With this command you will be asked for the password of target user

2. Using `sudo`:

`sudo -u user "command"`

With this command you execute it with or without password (your password)

3. Using `ssh`:

With ssh you can exec the command with password for user, password for the key (if any)

```
ssh user@localhost "command"
```

P.S. There are also other possible methods which are rarely possible like rsh

Comment: This helped me but, there must be someone else out there who thought the quotes were needed.  Nope.  From my trial-and-error at least with the `sudo` version:  The quotes will not help you.

Comment: there is a problem, after login in that way the environment is somehow not ready, commands not found

Comment: `su -` or `sudo -i` is not appropriate for usage inside scripts as it breaks execution until `ctrl+d` (e.i. logout)

Comment: @4xy, probably your comment is for the answer of Graham, because I do not see to offer such thing in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using the command `su [username]` allows you to run a command in the context of that user, from the current location. Using the following command `su - [username]` switches you to that users home directory. 
If you omit the username you are switching to root.

Comment: And the password? Do you want to source it plain from the script? You'd need to `sudo` the script to avoid be promted for the password.